# echo help for bash script to count seconds (and overwrite)

Tags: bash, echo, display

I'd like to have a counter on my terminal prompt.  I pass it a value from the command line in minutes.  It counts the seconds on the screen, without a newline, in other words, it shows 0, 1, 2, 3 etc...but overwriting the previous number.  How can I do that?  The script below does a newline for each second.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
seconds=$1*60
while (( $i < $seconds ))
do
  echo $i
  sleep 1
  ((i++))
done
```

Comment: [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return#Computers). Don't use `$i` inside `((`, just `((i < seconds))`

Comment: Instead of `echo $i`, do `printf '\r%d' "$i"`

Comment: thanks @KamilCuk and Willam Pursell both your suggestions work

Comment: The variable `SECONDS` is incremented by the shell itself each second; use that instead of `i`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Using `$i` inside `((...))` is fine, and can be preferable in some circumstances, as you'll get an error for `$i` if it hasn't been set, whereas `i` will silently expand to 0.

Comment: thanks @chepner I didn't know about SECONDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the width with a `*` operator:

```
while (( i < seconds )); do
   printf "\r%*d" ${#seconds} $i
   sleep 1
   ((i++))
done
```